# Add tag <b> in data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, tags, drop-down-menu

I want to add `<b>` tag in DataValueField of DropDownList as:

```
var data = source.Select(a => new A{f12 = <b> + a.f1 + </b> + a.f2, f3 = a.f3}).ToList(); // I want to bolder a.f1 string by <b> tag.
```

Then:

```
ddlDropDownList.DataSource = data;
ddlDropDownList.DataTextField = "f12";
ddlDropDownList.DataValueField = "f3";
ddlDropDownList.DataBind();
```

If I coding like above, I get unexpected results, The TextField displays bold `<b>` tag

Comment: obviously they are rendered as Text not a HTML tags, do this in ASPX rather than code behind

Answer (score 1):

You need to add string fragments, so add quotes:

```
var data = source.Select(a => new A{f12 = "<b>" + a.f1 + "</b>" + a.f2, f3 = a.f3}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to tinker with the Attributes field of the DropDownList? Like:

```
ddlDropDownList.Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bold");
```

Comment: I think he not want have bolded whole item, just a substring

Comment: @sasjaq: you right. I only want have bolded just a substring.